# How many Dwarves are left in Middle Earth?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

I read *The Hobbit* and the LOTR trilogy a while back, and watched the LOTR trilogy movies (but not The Hobbit movie). I don't remember ever getting a clear grasp of how large the Dwarven population in Middle Earth is. I know, from there being several full cities, that there was a substantial Elven population left, but I can't recall there being that many living Dwarves as of the fellowship of the ring.

Is there a canonical answer to how many Dwarves are left in Middle Earth during the time of the fellowship? Additionally, is there a canonical answer to how many Humans, Elves, and Hobbits were around at that time (to give me a better grasp of how large the Dwarven population was as a proportion of the total population of Middle Earth, the size and population of which I've never been entirely clear on)?

Comment: AFAIK there is no canonical estimate, the linked post gives as many details as we have.

Comment: I find it quite odd that this is marked as a duplicate. The two questions are obviously quite different. Just because the other has an answer to this question buried in it is no reason to mark this one as a duplicate. We are not dealing with a database where there should, ideally, be a single source of truth. The value of Stack Exchange sites is in people searching and finding questions or answers that match their questions... (and yes I know I'm about 4 years behind...)